# Don't see anonymous function inside named function in coffeescript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

Want to convert this JavaScript into coffeescript:

```
function tileMap(tileSet, map, inPicSize, tileSize) {
    this.draw = function(context) {
        for (var i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < map[i].length; j++) {
                context.drawImage(tileSet, (map[i][j][0] - 1) * inPicSize, (map[i][j][1] - 1) * inPicSize, inPicSize, inPicSize, j * tileSize, i * tileSize, tileSize, tileSize);
            }
        }
    };
}

// initialization
function init() {
    var pic = new Image(); // Create image
    pic.src = 'http://dl.dropbox.com/u/8307275/p/set.png';
    var mapArr = [
        [[1, 4], [1, 4], [1, 4], [1, 4], [1, 4], [1, 4], [1, 4], [1, 4]],
        [[1, 4], [1, 1], [2, 1], [3, 1], [1, 4], [1, 4], [1, 4], [1, 4]],
        [[1, 4], [1, 2], [2, 2], [3, 2], [1, 4], [1, 3], [1, 3], [1, 3]],
        [[1, 4], [3, 4], [2, 3], [3, 4], [1, 4], [1, 3], [1, 4], [1, 4]],
        [[1, 4], [3, 4], [2, 4], [3, 4], [1, 4], [1, 3], [1, 4], [1, 4]],
        [[1, 4], [1, 4], [1, 3], [1, 4], [1, 4], [1, 3], [1, 4], [1, 4]],
        [[1, 4], [1, 4], [1, 3], [1, 3], [1, 3], [1, 3], [1, 4], [1, 4]],
        [[1, 4], [1, 4], [1, 4], [1, 4], [1, 4], [1, 4], [1, 4], [1, 4]]
        ];
    var map = new tileMap(pic, mapArr, 32, 32);
    var canvas = document.getElementById("preview_canvas");
    canvas.width = 480;
    canvas.height = 320;
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    pic.onload = function() // When image loads
        {
        map.draw(context); // draw map
    };
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    init();
})
```

This code is works fine. Next I converting it into coffeescript:

```
tileMap = (tileSet, map, inPicSize, tileSize) ->
    this.draw = (context) ->
        for i in [0..map.length]
            for j in [0..map[i].length]
                context.drawImage(tileSet, (map[i][j][0] - 1) * inPicSize, (map[i][j][1] - 1) * inPicSize, inPicSize, inPicSize, j * tileSize, i * tileSize, tileSize, tileSize)

init = () ->
    pic = new Image()
    pic.src = 'http://dl.dropbox.com/u/8307275/p/set.png'
    mapArr = [
        [[1, 4], [1, 4], [1, 4], [1, 4], [1, 4], [1, 4], [1, 4], [1, 4]],
        [[1, 4], [1, 1], [2, 1], [3, 1], [1, 4], [1, 4], [1, 4], [1, 4]],
        [[1, 4], [1, 2], [2, 2], [3, 2], [1, 4], [1, 3], [1, 3], [1, 3]],
        [[1, 4], [3, 4], [2, 3], [3, 4], [1, 4], [1, 3], [1, 4], [1, 4]],
        [[1, 4], [3, 4], [2, 4], [3, 4], [1, 4], [1, 3], [1, 4], [1, 4]],
        [[1, 4], [1, 4], [1, 3], [1, 4], [1, 4], [1, 3], [1, 4], [1, 4]],
        [[1, 4], [1, 4], [1, 3], [1, 3], [1, 3], [1, 3], [1, 4], [1, 4]],
        [[1, 4], [1, 4], [1, 4], [1, 4], [1, 4], [1, 4], [1, 4], [1, 4]]
        ]
    map = new tileMap(pic, mapArr, 32, 32)
    canvas = document.getElementById("preview_canvas")
    canvas.width = 480
    canvas.height = 320
    context = canvas.getContext("2d")
    pic.onload = () ->
        map.draw(context)

$(document).ready ->
    init()
```

And I get error 'has no method "Draw"' caused when string

```
map.draw(context)
```

is executed. What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Any specific reason why you're not using the `class` CoffeeScript keyword for `tileMap`?

Comment: Amm... I don't know :) I'm new to coffeescript. So, I've just used `class` keyword, so this is how function looks now: 
`class tileMap
    constructor: (tileSet, map, inPicSize, tileSize) ->`
now I got error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined.
(First line of tiles has been draw) hmm, i guess it's error in loop

Comment: if you don't want to use `class`, you need to put `return this` at the end of `tileMap` because otherwise coffeescript returns the value of the last expression which in your case is the function `draw` itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a look at the compiled javascript, this is what the `tilemap` function looks like:

```
var tileMap;
tileMap = function(tileSet, map, inPicSize, tileSize) {
  return this.draw = function(context) {
    …
  };
};
```

Wait, what? Yes, it does return the `draw` function instead of the instance. All in all there are lots of unncessary `return` statements in the code… To solve this particular case, you either have to add an explicit `return this` in the end of the code or use the `class` syntax:

```
class tileMap
    constructor: (tileSet, map, inPicSize, tileSize) ->
        @draw = (context) ->
            for row, i in map
                for pic, j in row
                    context.drawImage(tileSet, (pic[0] - 1) * inPicSize, (pic[1] - 1) * inPicSize, inPicSize, inPicSize, j * tileSize, i * tileSize, tileSize, tileSize)
            return
```